# Php. Помогите усовершенствовать код

Tags: php

Вывести все элементы массива, по три в обертке.
Подскажите, как лучше реализовать, пока говнокод и понимаю сам.
Дан массив **$images** с числом изображений (число N). Нужно его обойти

```
Пример массива 

$images[0], $images[1], $images[n]
$images[0] => $images[0]['popup'],$images[0]['src']
$images[1] => $images[1]['popup'],$images[1]['src']
$images[n] => $images[n]['popup'],$images[n]['src']
```

---

```
$imax=count($images);
for ($i = 0 ; $i < $imax ; $i++) {
    print '<div class="item">';

    $images[$i]['popup']; 
    $i++;if($i==$imax){echo '</div>';break;} 

    $images[$i]['popup']; 
    $i++;if($i==$imax){echo '</div>';break;} 

    $images[$i]['popup']; 
    $i++;if($i==$imax){echo '</div>';break;} 

    print '</div>';
}
```

Вариант, решения, взятый из комментариев —

```
$tmpArray = array_chunk($image,3);
foreach($tmpArray as $_image) {
  echo '<div>';
  foreach($_image as $_subImage) {
     echo $_subImage;
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

и

```
function split_my($arr, $size)
{
    foreach(array_chunk($arr, $size) as $val)
    {
        echo "<div>".
             implode("", array_map(function($value){ 
                 return "<span> ".$value." </span>"; 
             }, $val)).
             "</div>";
    }
}
```

Comment: покажите пример массива

Comment: poprobuy poka eto poka pridumayu luchsh 
for ($i = 0 ,$imax=count($images),$cnt = 0; $i < $imax ; $i++) {
 $cnt++;
 if($cnt == 1){
  echo '<div class="item">';
  echo  '<span>'.$images[$i]['popup'].'<span>';
 }
 else
 {
  if($cnt == 3) $cnt = 0;
  echo  '<span>'.$images[$i]['popup'].'<span>';
 }
}

Comment: array_chunk и implode спасут вас

Comment: @splash58, эти функции облегчат вывод и получится меньше строк?

Comment: конечно. первой сразу побьете на нужные куски, второй соедините дивами

Comment: Вот и зря Вы не написали ответ! Вы самый первый, кто правильный ответ дал

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хорошо, я делаю обычно так.

Если мне требуется что-то сделать с массивом, я [открываю документацию и смотрю на встроенные функции](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.array.php), могут ли они мне помочь. Опа, смотрите, там есть [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php), почему бы и нет.

Но это не все, для прохождения по всем элементам подмассива можно использовать `map_array`, связать все это через `implode` и вывести. А давайте теперь все это оформим в универсальную функцию.

```
function split_my($arr, $size)
{
    foreach(array_chunk($arr, $size) as $val)
    {
        echo "<div>".
             implode("", array_map(function($value){ 
                 return "<span> ".$value." </span>"; 
             }, $val)).
             "</div>";
    }
}

$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
split_my($arr, 3);
```

Из минусов данного алгоритма - жрет память на создание копии массива `array_chunk`. Ну и у Вас это будет не `$value`, a `$value['popup']` насколько я понял.

Comment: Она не очень универсальная - html код перемешан с php. 
А вот что бы память не "жрало", можно воспользоваться array_slice

Comment: @KoVadim 1. Я сконцентрировался на основной задаче, вроде разделить разметку или подключить шаблонизатор, это уже дело простое. Тут главное обвязка под это. 2. Я попытался избавиться от получения длинны массива и доп.расчетов в явном виде. Если использовать array_slice придется считать offset и проверять вернувшийся массив на пустоту. А если использовать array_splice и избавится им от offset, то остается проблема с изменением исходного массива, что тоже может быть не хорошо и опять же проверка на пустоту. Поправьте, если где-то недодумал.

Comment: шаблонизатору можно просто вернуть результат array_chunk. я бы разделил на два куска. 

А вот боятся простых вычислений, но при этом сэкономив память и выиграв в скорости, не нужно. Но это все нужно профайлить, профайлить и ещё раз профайлить.

Comment: Я все же проголосую за Вас, суть ответа была в упрощении кода, для чего и служат те, функции, что Вы и использовали, я бы ради эксперимента использовал вместо implode foreach. Суть Вы донесли первее! Спасибо Вам огромное

Answer (score 2):

Я поправил решение

```
 $images = [
    ['popup'=>'AAA'],
    ['popup'=>'BBB'],
    ['popup'=>'CCC'],
    ['popup'=>'EEE'],
    ['popup'=>'FFF'],
    ['popup'=>'JJJ'],
];


function showItems($images, $step){
    $cnt = 0;
    for ($i = 0 ,$imgCnt=count($images); $i < $imgCnt ; $i++) {
        $cnt++;
        if($cnt == 1){
            echo '<div class="item">';
        }

        echo  '<span>'.$images[$i]['popup'].'</span>';

        if($cnt == $step or $i == $imgCnt-1){
            $cnt = 0;
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
showItems($images, 3);
```

Самое на мой взгляд оптимальное и короткое решение.
Функция универсальная .Выводит количество $images по заданному $step

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, но 1 div либо лишний, либо недостающий. Скорее лишний

Comment: so hard..........

Comment: Там лишнего ничего нет,все корректно открываться и закрывается.
Я сейчас постараюсь облегчить его

Comment: а если количество картинок не делится на цело на 3?

Comment: У меня было 5 каринок, поэтому что-то с числом дивов было не так

Comment: @Romuald Shmidtelson функция выведет 3 а потом 2 оставшихся diva.
Неужели так трудно протестировать передав функции 5 картинок ?

Comment: Я вечером буду тестировать и пройдусь по всем!

Comment: @Romuald Shmidtelson если вы считаете что какой нибудь ответ дан правильно,то прошу вас оценить  поставив галочку возле ответа или,нажать на стрелочку вверх возле него.Это поможет другим легче сориентироваться.Спасибо

Comment: Ваш вариант я проверил. Все работает, но это такое же извращение, что и у меня, скорее всего ничто лучше не решит проблему как array_chunk

Comment: в примере с 5-ю картинками. на пятой картинке `$cnt` будет равен 2, а `$step=3` в итоге последнее условие не выполнится и див не закроется

Comment: Да верно подмечено ,спасибо ,щас поправлю

Comment: @Romuald Shmidtelson тут код более оптимален чем с использованием функций,array_chunk будет каждый раз итерировать array,разбивать на части,запоминать их,потом рассчитывать индексы.При малом количестве картинок может и не будет ощутимо.
А при больших, это чревато потерью памяти,задержки сервера ...

Comment: Я не спорю, Ваш код отличный. Но под усовершенствованием я подразумевал уменьшение числа строк и избавление от $i, $++

Answer (score 1):

#### Итераторы кто-нибудь использует?

[`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.reset.php), [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.current.php), [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.next.php), [`prev()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.prev.php)

```
$i = 0;
$html = '';
reset( $images);
do {
    if( 0 === $i%3)   $html .= '<div class="item">';
    $html .= sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="">', current($images)['popup']);
    if( 0 === ++$i%3) $html .= '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
} while( next( $images));
if( 0 !== $i%3) $html .= '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
echo $html;
```

---

**Вариант** с [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-chunk.php) и [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php):

```
echo implode("\n", 
    array_map( 'wrapRow',
        array_chunk(
            array_map( 'wrapImage', $images),
            3
        )
    )
);
function wrapRow( $els) {
    return sprintf('<div class="item">%s</div>', implode('', $els));
}
function wrapImage($image) {
    return sprintf('<img src="%s" alt="">', $image['popup']);
}
```

Сначала из массива `$images` получаем массив тегов `<img>` где подставлен url из поля `popup`. Т.е. такой же длины массив, но там уже теги.

Потом бьём его на группы по три (или меньше в последней) с помощью `array_chunk()` – получаем массив из массивов по 3, или меньше, `<img>`.

Потом эти тройки склеиваем `implode()` и оборачиваем в `<div class="item">`.

И выводим, склеив `<div>`'ы символом новой строки.

---

Comment: сорри но downvote но немогу пройти мимо if в одну строку и т.д. и т.п. 
память на знаках переноса строки и `{}` в угоду восприятия экономить не кошерно.

Comment: на вкус и цвет минимайзера нет )

Comment: @Naumov, ничего страшного, я компенсирую)) Мне понравился вариант с использованием еще одного `array_map` и выносом функций за пределы, в отличие от моего ответа с внешним `foreach`.

Comment: Да нет не спорю но в первом варианте вы чистый `foreach` изобрели http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php судя по документации.

Comment: @Naumov, я несу в народ слово PHP'вое! : ) Здесь это чистый `foreach()`, но завтра, может, понадобится гулять по большому массиву взад и вперёд!

Comment: reset(), current(), next(), prev() это не итераторы а функции по работе с массивами.php SPL - ArrayIterator , Iterator и тд ,вот это да http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.interfaces.php

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan по-моему, можно считать перечисленные функции не-ооп реализацией интерфейса итератора ) Принцип тот же.

Comment: reset(), current(), next(), prev() это функции которые преставляют курсор в массиве.А вот foreach он оперирует.Впрочем  лучше знать как ими правильно пользоваться :)

Comment: Вы молодец. Но я выделю того, кто первее рассказал мне про функцию! Не смотря на Вашу базу знаний. Все равно Вам огромнейшее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не понимаю людей удаляющих ответы! вы что минусов боитесь рейтинг потерять?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($image) ; $i++) {
    if($i%3 == 0) {
        echo '<div>';
    }

    echo $image[$i];

    if($i%3 == 0) {
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
if($i%3!=0) {
   echo '</div>'; // что бы если в конце осталось 2-ва элемента закрыть div
}
```

или

```
$tmpArray = array_chunk($image,3);
foreach($tmpArray as $_image) {
  echo '<div>';
  foreach($_image as $_subImage) {
     echo $_subImage;
  }
  echo '</div>';
}
```

второй вариант лучше выглядет

Comment: Смысла нет, чего-то боятся. Без ошибок ничего не выйдет. Вечером буду все варианты пробовать. Определить лучший становится труднее

Comment: Просто там действительно ошибка была, а времени на исправление особо нет, так что решил не засорять.

Comment: @DanielOlivo У вас лишь одна ошибка, в конце вы ` if($i%3 == 0)` эту проверку деления на 3 заменили на что то другое по этому собственно и div недостающий ну и последнее конечно условие. А так ответ же правильный был.

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < count($image) ; $i++)

Tak nikogda nedelayut te kto ponimayut v optimizacii,potomuch to pri kajdoy iteracii budet podschitivatsya count($image),esli itraciy mnogo to ono sojret mnogo pamyati i vremeni.
a pravilno ego peremestit v perviy blok vot tak for ($i = 0,$cnt = count($image); $i < $cnt ; $i++),gde inicializaciya $cnt = count($image) budet odin raz i v ostalnix iteraciyax prosto budet postavlyatsya ego znachenie,chto namnogo luchshe,soglasits

Comment: Как по мне, так его лучше вообще вынести за цикл for надо

Comment: Второй вариант и есть ответ поста! Спасибо Вам огромнейшее